# Delete cells from the other workbook

Tags: excel

Sorry, now, How can I delete the data from the other Workbook?
I want delete the data that there are in the file Victoria.xlsx. This not working... Can you help me please? Thanks!!

```
Sub BorrarContenidoVictoria()

    Dim wbThat As Workbook
    Dim wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim wbThatPath As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change path accordingly
    wbThatPath = "/Users/jose/Desktop/Victoria.xlsx"

    Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open(wbThatPath)
    Set wsThat = wbThat.Sheets("Hoja1")

        lRow = wsThat.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        wsThat.Range("A2" & lRow).ClearContents


End Sub
```

Comment: are you trying to `Delete` them or `ClearContents` them? Your title and code go against each other. Those are two entirely different things

Comment: `wsThat.Range("A2" & lRow).ClearContents` should probably be `wsThat.Range("A" & lRow).ClearContents` or `"A2:A" & lRow`, I don't see why you'd need to append a 2 to the row number...

Answer (score 0):

This deletes all the cells in `Hoja1` of `Victoria.xlsx`:

```
Sub BorrarContenidoVictoria()

    Dim wbThat As Workbook
    Dim wsThat As Worksheet
    wbThatPath = "/Users/jose/Desktop/Victoria.xlsx"

    Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open(wbThatPath)
    Set wsThat = wbThat.Sheets("Hoja1")

    wsThat.Cells.Delete
    wbThat.Close True

End Sub
```

The `wbThat.Close True` closes the workbook and saves the changes - 
[Close Method MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel)

Comment: This script that you indicate delete the source sheet, it does not delete victoria.xlsx.

Thank you.

Comment: @JoséAntonioMoyanoAcosta - you mean that `wsThat.Cells.Delete` deletes the cells of the `ActiveSheet` and not the `Hoja1` in `wbThatPath`.

Comment: Correct @Vityata. This removes the cells from the source file, but I need to remove it from the destination file (victoria.xlsx). Thanks